# How to receive data back to flutter when calling a method using js.context.callMethod()?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am building a chrome extension using Flutter Web, which is just a simple `ListView` on the home screen and basic CRUD operations. I am using `dart:js` package to call methods from a JS file which performs some operations on the Firebase Realtime Database.

Adding a new entry to the database is **working** through the `add()` method call. Read operation is also working in the JS file just fine.

My main question is how I am supposed to **read** the database info as JSON, parse it and display it as `ListView` in Flutter.

---

Here goes `main.dart` and `AddAttendee.dart` -

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'AddAttendee.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Flutter Meet Attendance',
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Map> data;

  getAttendees() async {
    var obj = await js.context.callMethod('read');
    List<Map> users = (jsonDecode(obj) as List<dynamic>).cast<Map>();
    setState(() {
      data = users;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getAttendees();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Current Attendees"),
      ),
      body: data != null
          ? ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                  title: Text(data.toString()[index]), // I don't know how to read correctly
                );
              },
            )
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: 'Add to Attendance',
        child: Icon(Icons.person_add),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => AddAttendee(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddAttendee extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddAttendeeState createState() => _AddAttendeeState();
}

class _AddAttendeeState extends State<AddAttendee> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add to Attendance List"),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            autocorrect: false,
            autofocus: true,
            controller: _textController,
            onFieldSubmitted: (value) => _textController.text = value,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) return 'This field is mandatory';
              return null;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: "Done",
        child: Icon(Icons.done),
        onPressed: () {
          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            js.context.callMethod('add', [_textController.text]);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the JS code -

```js
const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();

var userList = [];

function read() {
  dbRef.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    userList = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      var user = childSnapshot.val();
      userList.push({ key, user });
    });
  });
  return userList;
}

function add(user) {
  let newUser = { name: user };

  dbRef.push(newUser, function () {
    console.log("Attendance Record Updated - New Attendee Added");
  });
}
```

Database structure in Firebase RT DB -

[image: firebase_RTDB]

Database structure when parsed -

[image: parsed_DB]

---

It's just so frustrating debugging this code because I can't `print` the outputs of the `main.dart` and if any error happens and an exception is thrown then it is displayed in form of transcompiled `main.dart.js` file which is impossible to read.

**I haven't been able to get the data back from the `read()` method in the JS file to `main.dart`. How to do that?**

Some links for reference -

https://twitter.com/rodydavis/status/1197564669633978368
https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/dyd8j5/create_chrome_extension_running_flutter/
https://github.com/rodydavis/dart_pad_ext/

Comment: What is the current output? I haven't had trouble retrieving output from `js.context.callMethod`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When calling `callMethod` it returns exactly what the javascript function returns. It doesn't return a json encoded `String` like your code currently implies. Therefore there is no need to decode it. `var obj` can *nearly* be treated as a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` object. This means you can access say the first object of the list and the `key` property with `js.context.callMethod("read")[0]['key']` in your dart code. You can remove all the json decoding and casting in your code and replace it with a function that uses this method of accessing the returned data to convert it to an actual `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` yourself.

Example `getAttendees` modification:

```
Future<void> getAttendees() async {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> toReturn = List();
  js.JsArray obj = js.context.callMethod("read");
  for(js.JsObject eachObj in obj) {
    //For every object in the array, convert it to a `Map` and add to toReturn
    toReturn.add({      
      'key': eachObj['key'],
      'user': eachObj['user'],
    });
  }
  setState(() {
    data = toReturn;
  });
}
```

If you for some reason find the need to use json, you would need to encode on the javascript side, though I don't see a reason to do this as it just adds complexity.

When displaying the data in the `build` function `data.toString()[index]` will first convert the javascript output to a `String` like this: `"[{key: key}, {key: key}, ...]"` and then find the `index` of the *`String`*, not the `List` object, which is likely what you intend. For this you use the index *first*, `data[index]` and then add the field you're looking for `data[index]['key']` as data is a `List` of `Map`s.

Unrelated directly to the problem you're having, but some general flutter advice, is to use a `FutureBuilder` instead of your current method of showing data when the `async` function completes. Your method *nearly* does what a `FutureBuilder` would, just a bit less efficiently and in a less readable way.

EDIT:
To handle `read` as a `Promise`:

First you have to add `js: ^0.6.2` to your `pubspec.yaml` dependencies.

Then this must be added somewhere in your code:

```
@JS()
library script.js;

import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'dart:js_util';

@JS()
external dynamic read();
```

`js.JsArray obj = js.context.callMethod("read");` Should be modified to just be `await promiseToFuture(read())`. The whole `getAttendees` should be modified to:

```
Future<void> getAttendees() async {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> toReturn = List();
  dynamic obj = await promiseToFuture(read());
  for(dynamic eachObj in obj) {
    //For every object in the array, convert it to a `Map` and add to toReturn
    toReturn.add({      
      'key': eachObj.key,
      'user': eachObj.user,
    });
  }
  setState(() {
    data = toReturn;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting effort into this question. I got the debugging to work, the error shows `Expected a value of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>', but got one of type 'JsObject'`. Implicit conversion is not taking place, we have to convert it explicitly from `JsObject`.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. My answer addresses this already. See my example code. I said it can _nearly_ be treated as that data type. My code does an explicit conversion.

Comment: This code doesn't work because of the `async` nature of the JS method `read()`. An empty array is returned from the method first, then the array is updated. I haven't been able to find a workaround for that. (I have modified the `read()` method to be async otherwise nothing works).

Comment: `read` isn't marked as `async` in what you posted. Is that a mistake? There are ways to handle promises still as well so that's not a problem, but it's not marked as async at the moment.

Comment: You can use the [`promiseToFuture`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-js_util/promiseToFuture.html) function, but only if `read` is really `async`.

Comment: You should modify your `read` function to return a `Promise`. `read` currently wouldn't even work in a pure JS environment.

Comment: @Abhishek Using `promiseToFuture` would involve using [package:js annotated JavaScript interop objects](https://pub.dev/packages/js) rather than `callMethod` with `dart:js`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Would you please edit your answer to include `promiseToFuture` implementation when the `read()` is `async`. I think lastly it will work as the sole solution to my specific problem. Thanks for investing time in this question.

Comment: yes that would definitely work as I have now refactored the code using js-dart interop

Comment: @Abhishek I modified my answer to accommodate for an `async` `read` method that returns a `Promise`.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks for sharing this awesome method. As I modified some code for my exact need I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since Christopher Moore gave a generalized solution to my problem, I will post an exact implementation I used.

**Database Structure -**

[image: database]

**JS Code -**

```js
const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();

var userList = [];

async function read() {
  await dbRef.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    userList = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      var user = childSnapshot.val();
      userList.push({ key, user });
    });
    //console.log(userList);
  });
  return userList;
}
```

**JS-Dart Interop -**

```dart
@JS()
library js_interop;

import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'package:js/js_util.dart';

@JS()
external dynamic read();

class FBOps {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> toReturn = [];

  Map getUserDetails(objMap) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> temp = {};

    temp['name'] = objMap.user.name;
    temp['status'] = objMap.user.status;

    return temp;
  }

  Future<List> getList() async {
    dynamic obj = await promiseToFuture(read());

    for (dynamic eachObj in obj) {
      toReturn.add({
        'key': eachObj.key,
        'user': getUserDetails(eachObj),
      });
    }

    return toReturn;
  }
}
```

**Getting the `Map` from interop -**

```dart
List<Map> data;

Future<void> getAttendees() async {
  await FBOps().getList().then((value) => data = value);
  //print(data);
}
```